# Mount .CDR File

Tags: mount, iso

I have a CD image which is in .cdr format. (Please note, it's not the same as a Corel Draw image - which also uses the .CDR extension).

Is there any way to open it on Ubuntu?  I don't have a local CD drive - I just want to extract the contents to my HDD.

It won't open with Brasero, I can't mount it, nor extract it from the file manager.

Is there any way to convert it to a standard ISO?

Comment: I can not check it right now, but did you try simply renaming a `.cdr` file to an `.iso` and them `mount`?

Comment: I did try that - sadly, it just says that it's not a valid image.

Comment: This question is a kind of duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/140976/how-to-burn-refit-cdr-or-dmg-in-ubuntu-or-windows .

Comment: This isn't a rEfit file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found *one* way to do it.

The disc was, apparently, an audio recording.  By using avconv / ffmpeg, I was able to extract the raw contents.

```
avconv -i image.cdr
```

Tells me the codec etc.  Then, to extract:

```
avconv -i image.cdr -acodec copy output.mkv
```

Answer (score 2):

Test this:

Given that Gnu/Linux has losetup which you can use to attach a file to the system as a block device.

You may be able to mount the image.cdr, with the following command:

```
sudo losetup /dev/loop0 image.cdr
```

Now you can use the image like a real cd.

Comment: Just comes back with `you must specify the filesystem type`

Answer (score 2):

CDR could be RAW Audio CD. Import it into **Audacity** via `File -> Import -> Raw Data` and setup appropriate settings.